# Compare three strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to compare three strings and take a different action based on which ones are the     same.

It seems to me there are 5 different outcomes:

- they are all the same (A=B=C)
- they are all different
- two of them are the same (A=B, B=C or C=A)

I'm struggling to write an efficient piece of Ruby code to give me the 5 different outcomes. Comparing strings seems quite an expensive operation and I don't want to repeatedly compare the same strings.

This code will run inside a loop so some optimisation seems like a good idea. This isn't my Comp Sci homework, it's a real-world problem :-)

[EDIT]
A further optimisation of Sergio's code gives even better results. We can defer the third string comparison until the `if...then` statement like this:

```
def compare a, b, c
  ab = a == b
  ac = a == c

  if ab && ac
    1
  elsif ab
    2
  elsif ac
    3
  elsif b == c
    4
  else
    5
  end
end
```

[EDIT]
Benchmarks for the solutions given today including my version of Sergios's code:

```
                   user     system      total        real
sawa1:         0.620000   0.000000   0.620000 (  0.625677)
izomorphius:   0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.025314)
sergio1:       0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.018039)
sergio2:       0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.030210)
dominic:       0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.015450)
```

I compared 1024-character strings 10,000 times each and reduced the result to a number in the range 1-5 to represent the original requirement to take a different action for each of the 5 possible outcomes.

[EDIT] Benchmarking code is here https://gist.github.com/3871698

Comment: "seems quite an expensive operation" - did you benchmark this? do you have to compare millions of strings per second?

Comment: I will benchmark some approaches and post my best attempt here. I thought it seemed like common sense that comparing strings is expensive (unless Ruby holds some kind of hash for each string that can be compared instead of the string itself).

Comment: This looks like premature optimization to me.

Comment: Well it's lazy optimization, I guess, because I'm asking StackOverflow :-) It's only premature if you invest some resources in it unnecessarily. I was hoping it was a well-known problem with a well-known solution (that only I didn't know).

Comment: I'm going to accept Sergio's answer because it ran a little faster in my benchmarks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my attempt. It performs 3 string comparisons at most (and at least :) ).

```
def compare a, b, c
  ab = a == b
  ac = a == c
  bc = b == c

  if ab && ac
    "a == b == c"
  elsif ab
    'a == b'
  elsif ac
    'a == c'
  elsif bc
    'b == c'
  else
    'a != b != c'
  end
end

compare '1', '2', '3' # => "a != b != c"
compare '1', '2', '2' # => "b == c"
compare '2', '2', '3' # => "a == b"
compare '1', '2', '1' # => "a == c"
compare '1', '1', '1' # => "a == b == c"
```

### Update

Here's yet another "clever" approach, now involving bitmasks. It returns you a code of your possible outcome.

```
def compare a, b, c
  res = 0
  res |= (a == b ? 1 : 0)
  res |= ((a == c ? 1 : 0) << 1)
  res |= ((b == c ? 1 : 0) << 2) if res == 0
  res
end

compare '1', '2', '3' # => 0
compare '2', '2', '3' # => 1
compare '1', '2', '1' # => 2
compare '1', '1', '1' # => 3
compare '1', '2', '2' # => 4
```

Comment: I believe my solution is faster by 33% in the case when a == b == c

Comment: Thanks Sergio. This certainly does what I asked. I was hoping to avoid the third string comparison in the cases where either a=b or a=c but not both, since in that case b cannot equal c. Anyway, as you suggest I will benchmark it and update this with any interesting results.

Comment: I like the look of the second option. Thanks again.

Comment: The first option ran fastest in my benchmarks, specially when modified to defer the third string comparison (see edit to original question)

Answer (score 4):

```
h = {a: "foo", b: "boo", c: "foo"}

h.group_by(&:last).values.map{|a| a.map(&:first)}
# => [[:a, :c], [:b]]
```

Or,

```
h.group_by(&:last)
# => {"foo"=>[[:a, "foo"], [:c, "foo"]], "boo"=>[[:b, "boo"]]}
```

Comment: I couldn't use the second option because the hash contains the original values and thus I'm back comparing stuff containing the original strings again.

Comment: The first option is very neat but seems to run a little slower than other less elegant solutions.

Answer (score 3):

```
ba=false
ca=false
bc=false
if b == a
  ba = true
  if b == c
    bc = true
    ca = true
  end
elsif c == a
  ca = true
elsif c == b
  bc = true
end
```

And now you have performed as few string comparison operations as possible. After you have the ab, bc and ca variables use them. That's it. You can't be better with respect to performance(but of course code style suffers from that).

Comment: Thank you, your code seems to establish which (if any) of the pairs are equal. What I need it to do is tell me which of the 5 actions I need to take. To do this I now need to compare the ba, ca and bc values repeatedly which is more efficient than comparing strings but still not as elegant as I'd like.

Comment: @DominicSayers Your question is not clear. You should specify an example input and the expected output of the script, as is usually the case with programming questions.

Comment: @sawa Thanks for your advice. I was going to post some sample code but you all beat me to it. Very grateful for all the contributions.

Comment: Even with the subsequent tests to examine the 3 booleans, this ran almost as fast as the quickest solution. I guess keeping it straightforward is often as good as anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
[string, string, string].uniq.count == 1
```